# Comparing elements in 2D ndarrays at the same position without for loops

Tags: python, numpy

Without having 4 for loops like this:

```
for row1 in range(0,size):
    for col1 in range(0,size):
        for row2 in range(0,size):
            for col2 in range(0,size):
                if (row1,col1) == (row2,col2):
                    #do something such as
                    #if (row1,col1,row2,col2) is in some other array
```

How can I vectorize this code to improve efficiency, allowing this to be done in one fellow swoop? (BTW, assume size is defined)

How can I iterate ONLY over the equal positions using numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function called `my_func(a, b)` that takes two scalars `a` and `b` as argument and returns another scalar.

Let's say your two 2d numpy arrays are `arr_a` and `arr_b`.

Then, the expression:

```
my_func(arr_a[:size,:size], arr_b[:size,:size])
```

will return a numpy array of shape `(size,size)`, such that each element in this result array is obtained by taking corresponding scalars from `arr_a` and `arr_b`, and passing them to `my_func(a,b)`

This works, as long as the stuff you do inside `my_func()` [conforms to certain rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).

For example, `my_func()` could be:

```
def my_func(a,b):
    return np.lcm(a,b)
```

or it could be:

```
def my_func(a,b):
    return a%b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dstack`(essentially a 2d version of zip) and `itertools.chain` together to achieve what you want.

```
In [1]: import itertools
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
In [4]: y = np.array([[9, 2, 7], [4, 3, 1]])
In [5]: x
Out[5]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [6]: y
Out[6]:
array([[9, 2, 7],
       [4, 3, 1]])


In [7]: for (a,b) in itertools.chain(*np.dstack((x,y))):
   ...:     if a==b:
   ...:         print("Equal")
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print("Not equal")
   ...:
Not equal
Equal
Not equal
Equal
Not equal
Not equal
```